# Easy way to get the boundary of a geometric object

Tags: differential-equations, geometry

I am trying to define von Neumann boundary conditions for a prism. To do so I need the boundary of the geometric object. I can't seem to find an easy way to do this. I have tried to hard code a parametric surface, but the sides of the prism (not faces) don't appear when I plot it. I think this is due to machine precision comparison.

To be precise, how do I define a boundary function for the geometric object defined by

```
R = Prism[{{0, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {-(1/2), 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 0}, {0, Sqrt[
 3]/2, 1}, {-(1/2), 0, 1}, {1/2, 0, 1}}];
```

Such that I can impose von Neumann boundary conditions on the following

```
nos = 10;
{vals, funs} = 
NDEigensystem[{{PDE[[1]], PDE[[2]], PDE[[3]]}, 
DirichletCondition[{ux[x, y, z] == 0, uy[x, y, z] == 0, 
  uz[x, y, z] == 0}, True]}, uv[x, y, z], {x, y, z} ∈ R, nos];
```

Comment: This is too vague to be answered. You must supply a  lot more detail to have any expectation of receiving an answer. As a start, please update your question with the _Mathematica_ code pertaining to your problem.

Comment: Would you be able to use RegionBoundary method to get what  you want? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBoundary.html